# Why does the order of inner join matter in F# query expression

Tags: f#, query-expressions

I am following an example from a book about query expression. I didn't type exactly as what's written in the book and somehow to my surprise the order of sequence matters even for an inner join query in F#. The book didn't mention anything about the order at all and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx) only says the order is significant. But why does it matter even for an inner join?

This doesn't compile and it says `namespace or module fa is not defined`; same for `f` :

```
query { for f in QuerySource.films do
        join fa in QuerySource.filmActors on (fa.FilmId = f.Id)
        join a in QuerySource.actors on (fa.ActorId = a.Id)
        select (f.Name, f.ReleaseYear, a.LastName, a.FirstName)
      }
```

But this does:
`query { for f in QuerySource.films do
        join fa in QuerySource.filmActors on (f.Id = fa.FilmId)
        join a in QuerySource.actors on (fa.ActorId = a.Id)
        select (f.Name, f.ReleaseYear, a.LastName, a.FirstName)
      }`

EDIT1: Don't think it matters but for clarification here is the `QuerySource` module

```
module QuerySource = 
    open System

type Film = {Id : int; Name: string; ReleaseYear : int; Gross : Nullable<float>}
            override x.ToString() = sprintf "%s (%i)" x.Name x.ReleaseYear

type Actor = {Id : int; FirstName : string; LastName : string}
             override x.ToString() = sprintf "%s %s" x.LastName x.FirstName

type FilmActor = {FilmId : int; ActorId : int}

let films = 
        [   {Id = 1; Name = "The Terminator"; ReleaseYear = 1984; Gross = Nullable 38400000.0}
            {Id = 2; Name = "Predator"; ReleaseYear = 1987; Gross = Nullable 59735548.0}
            {Id = 3; Name = "Commando"; ReleaseYear = 1985; Gross = Nullable 38122105.0}
            {Id = 4; Name = "The Running Man"; ReleaseYear = 1987; Gross = Nullable<float>()}
            {Id = 5; Name = "Conan the Destroyer"; ReleaseYear = 1984; Gross = Nullable<float>()}
        ]
let actors = [{Id = 1; FirstName = "Arnold"; LastName = "Schwarzenegger"}
              {Id = 2; FirstName = "Linda"; LastName = "Hamilton"}
              {Id = 3; FirstName = "Carl"; LastName = "Weathers"}
              {Id = 4; FirstName = "Jesse"; LastName = "Ventura"}
              {Id = 5; FirstName = "Vernon"; LastName = "Wells"}
             ]
let filmActors = 
    [ {FilmId = 1; ActorId = 1}
      {FilmId = 1; ActorId = 2}
      {FilmId = 2; ActorId = 1}
      {FilmId = 2; ActorId = 3}
      {FilmId = 2; ActorId = 4}
      {FilmId = 3; ActorId = 1}
      {FilmId = 3; ActorId = 5}
      {FilmId = 4; ActorId = 1}
      {FilmId = 4; ActorId = 4} // internationally omitted for filmid = 5
    ]`
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it says fa and f are not defined. Just added this to the question.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to quote the part of the F# spec that says that the order matters, or someone from the F# team to relate any internal discussions they may have had around this topic? Or do you want the only answer that really has any bearing: The order matters because that's the way the F# compiler was implemented.

Answer (score -3):

The Order is maybe significant as performance wise. In the case the joined tables have significantly different sizes, the query would start searching one of the tables for all correspondent values before starting the second table. if it started with the smaller table it would finish faster.

Comment: If it were for performance reason, why would it not even compile if the order is switched?